# xmpp/ejabberd user search commend returning empty fields

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

this is my query to ejabberd server running on localhost using window telnet to search whether user exists or not

local server host name is *durgesh-laptop*

```
<iq type="set" id="searchByUserName" to="vjud.durgesh-laptop"from="durgesh@durgeshlaptop">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:search">
<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
<field type="hidden" var="FROM_TYPE">
<value>jabber:iq:search</value> 
</field>
<field var="user">
<value>anand</value>
</field></x></query></iq>
```

server response is:-

```
<iq from='vjud.durgesh-laptop' to='durgesh@durgesh-laptop/Telnet Client'          id='searchByUserName' type='result'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
<x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='result'>
<title>Search Results for vjud.durgesh-laptop</title>
<reported><field type='text-single' label='Jabber ID' var='jid'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Full Name' var='fn'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Name' var='first'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Middle Name' var='middle'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Family Name' var='last'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Nickname' var='nick'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Birthday' var='bday'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Country' var='ctry'/>
<field type='text-single' label='City' var='locality'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Email' var='email'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Organization Name' var='orgname'/>
<field type='text-single' label='Organization Unit' var='orgunit'/></reported></x>
</query></iq>
```

it contain empty fields. No matter whether user exists or not it always response with empty field values
please tell me where i am doing wrong.